# React Native expo init doesnt have Metro Bundle developer tools

Tags: react-native, expo

I just did `npm start` in my `expo init` project

Normally on your terminal it should be like this

```
Starting project at <directory here>
Developer tools running on htp://localhost:<port number here>
Starting Metro Bundler
BIG QR CODE HERE
```

However, mine is missing the `Developer tools running on htp://localhost:<port number here>`. So mine only shows this:

```
Starting project at <directory here>
Starting Metro Bundler
BIG QR CODE HERE
```

As a result I cannot open it in my local host, meaning I cannot access the metro bundler developer tools, the  one where you have the option of running it on **Android**, **iOS**, **web** and where you can also choose the connection type to be **Tunnel**, **LAN** or **Local**

All there is is `Metro waiting on exp://192.168.1.116:19000` but I am unsure how to access that

Comment: Are you using mac or windows?

Comment: to be clear your only problem is the webpage that used to open immediately after running npm start is not showing anymore?

Comment: @LouaySleman I am using both, but doing this on mac

Comment: @FaysalB, correct. the "Metro Bundler" is not showing up. The part where in the bottom left, you can scan a QR code, and choose the connection between LAN, tunnel, etc.

Comment: if you just want to run simulators inside the cli press i for ios and a for android

Comment: You're right @FeysalB